# Make an Objective-C class final in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

It's a common practice to make Swift classes final unless inheritance is absolutely necessary, to encourage the use of composition instead. Swift enforces this regardless of the `final` keyword when importing to Objective-C, by setting the Objective-C attribute `objc_subclassing_restricted`. However, interfaces with these attributes are not imported to Swift as `final` classes as I'd expect.

How do I make an Swift class that has been imported from Objective-C `final`?

Comment: It seems this is impossible right now. Objective-C doesn't support `final` classes so Swift supposes that every Obj-C class is not final.

Comment: Well, trying to subclass something with `obj_subclassing_restricted` is a compiler error these days, so it does support them at compile time (of course, you can still do anything at runtime, it's Objective-C).

Comment: Nope, you are not distinguishing between language feature and compiler feature. `obj_subclassing_restricted` is a way how compiler transfers Swift finality to Obj-C. It's true you can abuse it to prevent subclassing in Obj-C but you can't expect that to be transferred to Swift. It's not a language feature. Another Obj-C compiler would just ignore that attribute.

Comment: Objective-C classes only use dynamic method dispatch model and unlike Swift there is no static method dispatch model in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

> to encourage the use of composition instead.

This is not the primary goal of `final`. Final classes benefit from compile-time optimizations - since the compiler knows the class is final, thus no methods will be overridden, it can skip the vtable lookup and go straight to the binary location of those methods.

Objective-C as a language doesn't have support for final classes, so unless the language evolves to include such, it doesn't make sense to have support for it on the Swift side.

Regarding the `objc_subclassing_restricted` you saw, the goal of that attribute is not to make the Swift class final, but to prevent it from being subclassed by Objective-C code. There's a nice dicussion about the attribute [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/cannot-subclass-a-class-with-objc-subclassing-restricted-attribute/5674/3), one relevant quote:

> You cannot subclass a Swift class (even if it is a subclass of NSObject and available to the Objective-C runtime) because of deliberate limitations baked into Obj-C to block subclassing Swift classes in Obj-C code.